# PHP code does not execute

Tags: php, execute

I started learning PHP today and I've been trying to make a "Hello World" program, but when I type the code into the editor it does not appear in the browser, it's commented. What might be the issue ? I have XAMPP installed, and enabled Apache.

Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ColcN.png
Browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SH5FF.png

Comment: You should use `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` and not `<?echo...`.

Answer (score 2):

You are having

```
<?echo
```

Change to `<?php`

Every code that is PHP must be within the `<?php ?>` tags.

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone :)